# Difference between JavaServer Faces and "Java EE JSF"

Tags: jsf, weblogic

In the release notes for [WebLogic 12.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#CJAFAHGI), it states, "JavaServer Faces" 2.2 is supported but it also says, "Java EE JSF" 2.1.* is supported in another line.

Can anyone help me understand the difference between "JavaServer Faces" and "Java EE JSF"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't expect there is any difference. Sounds like incomplete documentation update.